# Effect "AuthEffects.authLogin$" dispatched an invalid action: undefined

Tags: angular, redux, rxjs, observable, side-effects

In an Angular 6 (and RxJS) application I have an Effect that manages the Login. It first calls the server and then sets and decodes the token. At the end I added a last operation which handles the redirect.

This is the case:
User (not logged in) try to access in Profile page. In the AuthGuard I intercept it and I save the desired page (auth-guard.service.ts):

```
 .. Here I already know that the user is not authenticated.
let url = state.url;
  if (url) {
       .. I save in the Store the url
       this.store.dispatch(new CoreActions.SaveRedirectUrl(url));
 }
 this.router.navigate(['/login']);
 return false;
```

This is the last two part of the Auth Effect (**auth.effects.ts**, called when i dispatch the action **DO_LOGIN**):

```
, mergeMap((tokenObj: any) => {
    return [
        {
            type: AuthActions.LOGIN 
        },
        {
            type: AuthActions.SET_TOKEN,
            payload: tokenObj.token
        },
        {
            type: ProfileActions.DECODE_TOKEN,
            payload: tokenObj.token
        }
    ];
})
, exhaustMap(() => {
    return this.store.select('core')
        .pipe(
            map(coreState => {
                if (coreState.redirectUrl) {
                    this.router.navigate([coreState.redirectUrl]);
                } else {
                    this.router.navigate(['/']);
                }
                new CoreActions.RemoveRedirectUrl();
            }));
}),
```

So I'm looking at this behaviour: after the the user has logged in, I save the token, I (eventually) redirect in the desired page, and then I remove that page from the State. I'm sure that the first mergeMap() works.. everything was broken when I added the last piece (exhaustMap), and I can not find a solution for the console error:

> ERROR Error: Effect "AuthEffects.authLogin$" dispatched an invalid action: undefined

If I change the position of the last "return":

```
this.store.select('core') -----> from here
    .pipe(
        map(coreState => {
            if (coreState.redirectUrl) {
                this.router.navigate([coreState.redirectUrl]);
            } else {
                this.router.navigate(['/']);
            }
            return new CoreActions.RemoveRedirectUrl(); -----> to here
        }));
```

I have a compilation error on exhaustMap():

> Argument of type '() => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: { type: string; payload?: undefined; } | { type: string; payload: any; }, index: number) ...'.
>     Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'ObservableInput<{}>'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using **Angular 6** and `rxjs 6.0.0`:

I had a similar issue recently managing my `ngrx` login and followed a similar pattern to what you are describing above.  In my `$login` effect, I originally had:

```
@Effect()
  login$ = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType<Login>(AuthActionTypes.Login),
    map(action => action.payload),
    exhaustMap((auth: Authenticate) =>
      this.authService.loginWithUsernameAndPassword(auth).pipe(
        map(user => {
          if (user && user.token) {
            this.cookieService.set('token', user.token)
          }
          new LoginSuccess({user})
          return user;
        }),
        catchError(error => of(new LoginFailure(error)))
      )
    )
  );
```

I was returning the `user`, which was giving me an error, so I dropped that and just tried to create the `new LoginSuccess({user})`.  That, though, was also giving me an error similar to the errors you are describing above.  What I figured was that the `map()` function inside of `pipe()` doesn't want side effects.  I wound up solving my problem just by using [`tap()`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/tap) to create my "side effect" of using my `cookieService` because [`tap()`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/tap) returns the same object that goes into it.  Once I did this, everything worked as intended -- no errors or exceptions.

```
@Effect()
  login$ = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType<Login>(AuthActionTypes.Login),
    map(action => action.payload),
    exhaustMap((auth: Authenticate) =>
      this.authService.loginWithUsernameAndPassword(auth).pipe(
        // user tap to set my cookie and achieve my side effect
        tap(user => {
          if (user && user.token) {
            this.cookieService.set('token', user.token)
          }
        }),
        // use map without any side effect
        map(user => new LoginSuccess({ user })),
        catchError(error => of(new LoginFailure(error)))
      )
    )
  );
```

Comment: its strange, map lets you do side effects but does not like it when you do so.